# Authentication failure when attempting GET via Google Scripts (curl works though)

Tags: google-apps-script, http-get, http-status-code-401, urlfetch

I'm trying to pull data into google sheets from another site via their API (https://api.motorsportreg.com/). All attempts running from the Google Apps Scripts interface returns a 401 error

> *Unauthorized (incorrect or missing username and password)*.

Their API uses the Basic Authentication plus an Organization ID. Using Postman, I can successfully get the data I'm requesting using the following cURL command (I've modified any IDs or keys).

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.motorsportreg.com/rest/events/88888888-xxxx-8888-xxxxxxxxxxx/assignments.json' \
--header 'X-Organization-Id: 777777-qqqq-7777-qqqqqqqqqq' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic 5t5t5t5t5t5t5=='
```

Within the Google Apps Script, I've tried various combinations pulled from other StackOverflow answers and google groups (like using 'options' instead of 'params' as well as different usage of single and double-quotes and placing quotes around Authorization) but so far the same results. I originally was using variables to calculate the authorization value (using Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)), pulling username and password information as well as the Organization ID from a Google sheet.

However, I eventually just hardcoded them into my script to cut down on as many elements that might be causing the issue. I've ended up with the following:

```
function callMSRAPI(event_id) {

  
  // pick up the API parameters from the Google Sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 
    var API_URL = 'https://api.motorsportreg.com/rest/events/';
    var USERNAME = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
    var PASSWORD = sheet.getRange(3,2).getValue();

  
//places authentication information in the correct format
  var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);

//Sets up the Header information; the authHeader above as well as the X-Organization-Id that is required for some GET operations  
    var headers = {
        'X-Organization-Id': '777777-qqqq-7777-qqqqqqqqqq',
        Authorization : 'Basic 5t5t5t5t5t5t5=='
      };
//I saw some samples that used this. Some placed the header information above directly in the options variable; others just referenced it like below.    
//    var options = {
//      "headers" : headers
//    };

//I saw a comment on another page that used this instead of options above.     
  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers' : headers
  };
   
   Logger.log(authHeader);
   Logger.log(headers) ;
 
  // Call the MSR API - Returned JSON has the data needed in the "assignments" portion
//  var assignments = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL + event_id + "/assignments.json");
  var assignments = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.motorsportreg.com/rest/events/88888888-xxxx-8888-xxxxxxxxxxx/assignments.json");
  
  Logger.log(assignments.getContentText());
  
// Parse the JSON reply
//  var json = JSON.parse(assignments.getContentText());
//  return json;
  
}
```

When logging what the variables are (and I'm assuming what's being sent) I get the following:

> [20-07-28 14:29:54:035 PDT] {Authorization=Basic cnQ0bWU6c3ViYnkxNw==,
> X-Organization-Id=3DDB6868-DB7D-CDB7-CF4FB9C00F6706DA} [20-07-28
> 14:29:54:230 PDT] Exception: Request failed for
> https://api.motorsportreg.com returned code 401. Truncated server
> response:

I don't know if it's an issue, but I do see where the working cURL command is using colons and single quotes around each piece of data whereas the Google log shows converting the colons to equal signs and has no quotes. I also see it's re-ordered the header information.

I'm just dipping my toe into programming so the terminology used above might not be quite correct. Thanks in advance for any assistance you might be able to provide.

Comment: 1. Show your full script. 2. Please link the official documentation, when asking questions about api.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the link to the documentation page for the API as well as my full function code. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Try urlencoding ``88888888-xxxx-8888-xxxxxxxxx``

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did a little reading and found references to encodeURI and encodeURIComponent. I tried using 
`var urlenc = encodeURIComponent('88888888-xxxx-8888-xxxxxxxxx');
var assignments = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.motorsportreg.com/rest/events/" + urlenc + "/assignments.json");`
and when that didn't change the behavior I tried
`var urlenc = encodeURI('https://api.motorsportreg.com/rest/events/88888888-xxxx-8888-xxxxxxxxx/assignments.json');
var assignments = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlenc);` but same 401 error occurred.

Comment: *specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.*. Try checking for this header in the response

Comment: Btw, your  username and password is visible in the log. Reset it in the api.